# PHP array structure $arr[ ( $arr[$arr] ) ] explaination

Tags: php

I've been given some code and one line is:

```
 $key = $arr[($arr[$arr])];
```

I've never seen () in [] before, and Googling around I can't seem to find an explanation.

I don't know the value of $arr, but I wish to set it.

Doing:

```
$arr = 'blah';
$key = $arr[($arr[$arr])];
```

gives me `Warning: Illegal string offset 'blah'`

So I cannot print_r on it to find out what it looks like.

Comment: Setting `$arr` to a string then trying to treat it like an array is ... not going to work.

Answer (score 2):

In general, there's nothing magical or strange here; the expression `($arr[$arr])` is equivalent to the expression `$arr[$arr]`, just as `(2)` is equivalent to `2`. At worst, the parens are redundant.

That being said, keys cannot have array-type, so trying to look up an element in an array using itself as a key is .... meaningless....